# My TikZ output is omitting nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-node

I really don't understand why this is happening, so I thought it was a bug from TeXStudio, but when I went on TeXShop and created a MWE it persists.  I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\tikzstyle{style1}=[rectangle, rounded corners, text centered, draw=black, fill=red, text width=7em]
\tikzstyle{arrow}=[very thick, ->, >=latex]
\tikzstyle{title}=[text centered, text width=6em, circle, draw=black, fill=blue]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def \radius {9em}

        \path (90 :\radius) node[style1](n1){n1}
        (145:\radius) node[style1](n2){n2}
        (180:\radius) node[style1](n3){n3}
        (215:\radius)node[style1](n4){n4};
        (270:\radius)node[style1](n5){n5};
        (325:\radius)node[style1](n6){n6};
        (0:\radius)node[style1](n7){n7};
        (35:\radius)node[style1](n8){n8};


        \node[title]{Big Title};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: This is my output]

Where did my final four nodes go off to?  I can't figure it out!

The reason I thought it was a bug was because TeXStudio is weird every so often and does this thing where it will always jump back to a previously-built document, despite the code...  It's really strange.

Anyway, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check out semicolons.

Comment: The first semicolon closes the `path`, the rest is thrown away... Just remove all semicolons minus the last one (or add more `path` commands).

Comment: You can shorten your code as `\foreach \i/\angle in {1/90,2/145,3/180,4/215,5/270,6/325,7/0,8/35}{
    \path (\angle :\radius) node[style1](n\i){n\i};}
    \node[title](BB){Big Title};`

Comment: Ah, thank you @ferahfeza.  Bit of a noob question... Sorry!  And thanks for the suggested code.  I never really knew how to use the `\foreach` command, so thanks for that!

Comment: @ChristopherTatlock, your welcome.

Comment: `\tikzstyle` is deprecated. Please consider using `\tikzset` instead, e.g. `\tikzset{arrow/.style={very thick, ->, >=latex}}`.

Comment: @ferahfeza Please post an answer.

Comment: @JouleV, unecessary. Just a code correction.

Comment: Ok, answer is posted.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned @Romano, the first semicolon closes the `\path`. Also as mentioned @marmot, `\tikzstyle` was converted to `\tikzset`

```
\documentclass[margin=3.1415mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\tikzset{style1/.style={rectangle,rounded corners,  text centered, draw=black, fill=red, text width=7em}}

\tikzset{title/.style={text centered, text width=6em, circle, draw=black, fill=blue}}

\tikzset{arrow/.style={very thick,->, >=latex}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def \radius {9em}
    \foreach \i/\angle in {1/90,2/145,3/180,4/215,5/270,6/325,7/0,8/35}{
    \path (\angle :\radius) node[style1](n\i){n\i};} 
    \node[title](BB){Big Title};
    \draw[arrow] (n1.270)--(n2.90); 
    \draw[arrow] (BB.270)--(n5.90); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]